# WordPress RESTAPI - Restrict unknown

Tags: rest-api

I am not sure about the technical term for what I am looking. However, I have done this in Laravel using [middleware](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192041/laravel-token-middleware). I am trying to achieve same in WordPress RESTApi.

I am planning to make a site as a service using WordaPress rest api. That I will use for cross platform. Since anyone can access WordPress api it is too dangerous.

I want to block it for public and only who pass the access token (not JWT or oAuth) I wan to allow only them to access API. This how I can limit the access.

So if I make android app and pass the access token, it will have access but anyone who want to make app from my api they want be able to.

I hope I have explained it properly to understand. You can see my middleware code that might help to explain more.

Comment: Why not JWT or oAuth?

Comment: That is user specific not the device specific. I mean I want a token to even access the root of application. Means even to access the login api or register api have to pass the token.